# Как выводить значение input в массив

Tags: javascript

Есть два input и один button. При нажатии кнопки: первый input должен выводить ключ в ассоциативный массив, а второй значения ключа. Как это реализовать?

```
<input type="text" class="inpt_key">
<input type="text" class="inpt_val">
<button class="btn">Push</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = {};
function toArray() {
  arr[document.querySelector('.inpt_key').value] = document.querySelector('.inpt_val').value;
  console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inpt_key">
<input type="text" class="inpt_val">
<button class="btn" onclick="toArray()">Push</button>
```